Why does Flutter api doesn't response in github pages
I have written a Weather App and it works in devices and simulators
but after i deployed on github pages, the api doesn't responed anything.
pubspec.yaml :
name: weatherapp
description: WeatherApp with Flutter by HesamZs
publish_to: 'hesamzs'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/day/
    - assets/images/night/

My github Repo : Click !
I've tried to check respones of api but it doesn't return anything in Console.
just i want to show my app in web from github pages.
Solution
Just add in http API request method function :
   headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
    "Accept": "*/*"
  },

